# Simple password login/logout using django and session storage. Stay logged in not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, session, passwords

I am trying to make a password protected page in a website using django.  There is no need for any username, just a user to enter a password to gain access.  That's fine, but I've got a checkbox so that they can choose to stay logged in for the session, but then on the actual protected page itself, a logout button should they wish to.  My idea is to set a session variable when submitting the log in form if the box is checked, check for that variable at the start of the function to go straight to the page if it exists on revisiting and to delete the variable and return to login page if logout is pressed.
However I can't make it work, I am trying all sorts of syntaxes.. does it want the session variable to be a dictionary?
I'm quite a novice and not very good at knowing syntax.  If someone could look at my functions and help I'd be very grateful.

```
def investors(request):
    """ A view show the investor login page (or investors page if a correct password is in session) and load the investors page if a correct password is entered. Also set a session variable that staylogged is ture if the stay logged in box is checked"""

    if request.session.get(['staylogged'] == True):

        return render(request, 'home/investors.html')
    else:
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            password = request.POST.get("password")
            staylogged = request.POST.get("staylogged")
            if (password == os.environ.get('INVESTOR_PASSWORD')):
                if staylogged:
                    request.session['staylogged'] = {
                        'staylogged': True
                        }
                return render(request, 'home/investors.html')
            else:
                return redirect('investorerror')

        return render(request, 'home/investorlogin.html')


def logout(request):
    """A view to change the staylogged in session variable to false and return to the login page"""
    request.session['staylogged'] = {
        'staylogged':False
    }
    return redirect('investors')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your `stay_logged` check isn't working is because the `GET.get()` is not just getting the dict but also checking `== True` for some reason. See my adjustments below:

```py
if request.session.get('staylogged').get('staylogged') == True:
```

The reason why I have two `.gets` is because your `staylogged` session value is a dict within the session dict, which I would suggest removing.

Comment: Ok, that all made a lot of sense and I've changed it and scrapped the dict. (I just put that in at one point as a response to one of the errors I got).  I've now got it like this and staylogged is working..BUT now, logout isn't.. is there more to do to change a session variable than just what I've got:   


    `request.session['staylogged'] = False`

Comment: For good measure I've also tried: `  del request.session['staylogged']` or `  request.session.flush()` None of them are making my logout button work!  Thanku so much for this help btw

Comment: That's strange, I can get it to worth within my own codebase. I wonder if it's your redirect to `investors` that is causing the issue. I would add `print(request.session.items())` to both views as well as the if-blocks and track when it gets created or updated

Comment: It does work now.  The problem was with my url path.  Because I wanted to redirect to investors in the logout view I had used '/investors/' as the url path for that as well.  I thought that was just the slug but it was actually directing to the wrong view.  Another novice mistake, I will know not to do that again.  So I gave it its own path '/logout/' and now it works fine :-) Thank you so very much for your help, I am so happy this is solved.